# Devops publish test results when the unit tests fails

Tags: docker, unit-testing, .net-core, azure-devops

I'd like to publish the result of the unit tests in Azure Devops

When the tests pass all works nice, the problem is when some test fails, becuase de Docker image is not generate and I can`t get the trx file.

I see a lot of samples, and all the people configure the same way the Dockerfile and Azure Pipeline yaml, but I don't know what I have wrong.

Here an extract of my Dockerfile:

```
RUN dotnet restore "IESA.TC.Invoices/IESA.TC.Invoices.csproj" COPY . .

FROM build AS test LABEL test=true WORKDIR /src/IESA.TC.Invoices.Tests RUN dotnet test -c Release --logger trx

FROM build AS publish WORKDIR "/src/IESA.TC.Invoices" RUN dotnet publish "IESA.TC.Invoices.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final WORKDIR /app COPY --from=publish /app/publish . COPY --from=test /src/IESA.TC.Invoices.Tests/TestResults ./TestResults
```

Here yaml file:

```
- stage: Build_Back_NewAKS
  displayName: Back - Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool: Dani test      
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnectionAcrack)
        repository: $(imageRepositoryBack)
        command: 'build'
        Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePathBack)

    
    - pwsh: |          
       $id=docker images --filter "label=test=true"  -q | Select-Object -First 1       
       docker create --name testinvoices $id
       docker cp testinvoices:/app/TestResults ./TestResults
       docker rm testinvoices
       condition: succeededOrFailed() 
       displayName: 'Copy test results'




- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: always() 
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/TestResults'
  displayName: 'Publish test results'
```

The docker build task ends with this error:

```
#19 16.74 Failed!  - Failed:     1, Passed:   128, Skipped:     0, Total:   129, Duration: 1 s - /src/IESA.TC.Invoices.Tests/bin/Release/net6.0/IESA.TC.Invoices.Tests.dll (net6.0) #19 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet test -c Release --logger trx]: exit code: 1

[test 2/2] RUN dotnet test -c Release --logger trx:

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet test -c Release --logger trx]: exit code: 1 ##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

The next step is unable to get the image

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\agent_work_temp\0f7433c8-e7e9-491e-bfc7-ba396cb81e70.ps1'" "docker create" requires at least 1 argument. See 'docker create --help'.

ocker create [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Create a new container 
Error: No such container:path: testinvoices:/app/TestResults 
Error: No such container: testinvoices
```

I tried to change "dotnet test run command " in Dockerfile to return exit code 0, but in this case I don't know when the tests fails.

Comment: Does it work without using azure pipeline?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?